# Como conectar una api en Angular

Tags: java, angular, api, spring-boot

Buen día. Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y me estoy topando con un error que es muy simple aparentemente pero no se como resolverlo. Estoy desarrollando una api en Angular y Java con Spring boot. Tengo una clase controller, una repository, una service y una model, por cada componente de angular (about, banner). En cada clase controller tengo la url que corresponde a ese elemento:

```
@GetMapping ("/portfolio/banner") 
@GetMapping ("/portfolio/about")
```

En angular tengo un servicio desde donde consumo la api. El echo es que cuando llamo a un componente se muestra perfectamente pero no se como agregar los demás llamados a la api.
Este es el codigo del servicio:

````
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PorfolioService {
url:string="http://localhost:8080/portfolio";


 constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }
obtenerDatos(): Observable<any> {

 return this.http.get(this.url+"/about");
 
}
}  ```

Gracias.
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero deberias de crear una interfaz de los datos de la API, si es que no la tienes ya en tu Proyecto, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, una de ellas es por ejemplo, hacer la llamada GET a la api por [Postman](https://www.postman.com) y copiar, la respuesta que te da, para luego irte a una página o usar una herramienta de conversión de tipo de datos, como por ejemplo [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io)

Allí pegas el código en la zona de la izquierda y en la derecha seleccionas el lenguaje que desees, (que en caso de Angular será "Typescript") y marcas la opción de "**Interfaces only**"

Ahora que ya tienes la interfaz, puedes construir y mandar objetos a tu API, para GET, POST, PUT o DELETE, entre algunas cosillas mas

Te dejo por aquí algunos ejemplos de los métodos que te faltan de esos 4:

EJEMPLO DE POST

```
 introducirDatos(datos: Datos): Observable<Datos> {
   return this.http.post<Datos>(this.url+"/about", datos, httpOptions);
 }
```

EJEMPLO DE PUT

```
editarDatos(datos: Datos): Observable<Datos> {
  return this.http.put<Datos>(this.url+"/about", datos, httpOptions);
}
```

EJEMPLO DE DELETE

```
borrarDatos(id: number): Observable<unknown> {
  const url = `${this.url}/about/${id}`; // por ejemplo: url/about/32
  return this.http.delete(url, httpOptions) 
}
```

Si no tienes un httpOptions, creo que no hace falta ponerlo, y estaría bien que usaras un pipe para los handler de error de esos métodos, poniéndolo justo después del Observable del return, **ejemplo**:

```
return this.http.delete(url, httpOptions)
  .pipe( catchError(this.handleError('borrarDatos')))
```

Comment: Si si, efectivamente tengo una interface implementada. Pero si por ejemplo yo quisiese hacer otro llamado get a otra url ¿Cómo lo hago? Por ejemplo si quiero llamar a esta otra url mediante GET `@GetMapping ("/portfolio/banner") ` ¿debería de hacer algo como esto? `return this.http.get(this.url+"/about"+"/banner"); `. ¿O como podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿La interface del lado de Angular de la que me hablas se puede implementar del lado del back? Te consulto porque quizá necesite además una interface del lado del cliente.

Comment: Buenas, no se si ya lo habrás solucionado, si no, respondiendo a tus preguntas,
la primera: con la variable url que tienes definida, con ese ejemplo estarías llamando a http://localhost:8080/portfolio/about/banner, no se como lo tienes estructurado a parte de los @GetMapping que tienes ahí, pero debería de ser `return this.http.get(this.url+"/banner");` 

Y a lo segundo, Si, necesitas la Interfaz en el front, para usarla en los métodos del http

Comment: buenísimo! Muchas gracias!!